# datetime.datetime.strptime() using variable input length

Tags: python, c, datetime, ubuntu

datetime.datetime.strptime seems to force directive matching regardless of the actual string length used. By using shorter strings, the directives will force the datetime.datetime object to use "something" in the string regardless of actual directives.

This is the correct behavior with enough input to fill the directives

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20180822163014', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 16, 30, 14)
```

This directives however will change the previous parsing

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20180822163014', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 16, 30, 1, 400000)
```

Is there any way to drop rightmost directives if input string is not long enough instead of cannibalizing the left ones?

I've tagged C and ubuntu because documentation says

> "The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms,
>   because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and
>   platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes
>   supported on your platform, consult the strftime(3) documentation."

EDIT:

`man ctime` shows the following structure as output. It is interesting that the microseconds ( %f ) precision doesn't seem to be supported.

```
struct tm {
     int tm_sec;    /* Seconds (0-60) */
     int tm_min;    /* Minutes (0-59) */
     int tm_hour;   /* Hours (0-23) */
     int tm_mday;   /* Day of the month (1-31) */
     int tm_mon;    /* Month (0-11) */
     int tm_year;   /* Year - 1900 */
     int tm_wday;   /* Day of the week (0-6, Sunday = 0) */
     int tm_yday;   /* Day in the year (0-365, 1 Jan = 0) */
     int tm_isdst;  /* Daylight saving time */
};
```

Comment: I tried looking up the `strptime` implementation to see if anything weird was going on. Contrary to the docs, [it seems to have been pure-Python since 2002](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/_strptime.py).

Comment: Although the docs only say Python calls the platform's strftime, not the platform's strptime, so while the docs are confusing and unclear, it may not be an outright contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you have to do it by yourself, which doesn't seems to hard because you know the pattern.
Something like that should to the job

```
pattern = ""
if len(s) == 0: raise Exception "empty time string"
if len(s) <= 4: pattern += "%Y"
... # as many if as you need here

datetime.datetime.strptime(s, pattern)
```

Which is very painful to write if you have long date pattern, but I doubt that there is some function doing it already in the datetime module - for the reason that its just a binding with C.

You can try to do something more generic and ask if it could be add to the datetime module.

Comment: I'd say it's easier to pad input with zeroes. `s.ljust(20)`. But I'd prefer the function to have consistent behavior

Comment: It's a C binding, and the philosophy in C is "if you give an unexpected input you'll probably have and unknown behavior; and it's your problem". Because when you use C, you want to be super efficient, so you just assume that the input is right and let the user do the check if he wants to.